# Ant exec task: How can I read input from console stdin?

Tags: ant, console, exec, stdin

I have a call to Ant `exec` task that needs to accept input from console stdin.  Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to do this.  The stdin filehandle seems closed to console input at runtime.

It is possible to specify input using attributes `input` and `inputstring`.  However, I need to prompt for user input at the console.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) of the task:

> Note that you cannot interact with the
>   forked program, the only way to send
>   input to it is via the input and
>   inputstring attributes. Also note that
>   since Ant 1.6, any attempt to read
>   input in the forked program will
>   receive an EOF (-1). This is a change
>   from Ant 1.5, where such an attempt
>   would block.

You could try to use the [input-task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html) to prompt for input in the ant-buildfile and pass these input with the inputstring-attribute of exec. I can't think of a better option at the moment.