# How to execute sonar command line in NAnt

Tags: maven, input, exec, nant, sonarqube

I want to use NAnt to execute sonar to scan my C# code. The sonar command line is "mvn sonar:sonar", in which 'mvn' is the command name, 'sonar:sonar' is the user name and password.
I tried two ways to execute it:

1.

```
<target name="buildOM" description="......">
    <exec program="mvn" workingdir="C:\codes\projects\helloworld">
        <arg value="sonar:sonar"/>
    </exec>
</exec>
```

2.

```
<target name="buildOM" description="......">
    <exec program="mvn sonar:sonar" workingdir="C:\codes\projects\helloworld">
    </exec>
</exec>
```

But these do not work. I found 'input' tag for Ant. "[Ant : Passing username and password to exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146063/ant-passing-username-and-password-to-exec)". But I cannot find it in NAnt help document.
I try to search the solution in the internet for 2 days, but failed.

Could you help me how to resolve it ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about calling the command shell and running maven within it?  Something like below...

```
<target name="buildOM" description="......">
    <exec program="cmd.exe" workingdir="C:\codes\projects\helloworld">
        <arg value="/c mvn sonar:sonar"/>
    </exec>
</exec>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your solution can do it well. As an alternate, I found another way similar to yours.
    <target name="buildOM" description="Scan and build the sonar OM project">
        <echo message="Build the sonar OM project" />
        <exec program="C:\tool\plug-in\maven\bin\mvn.bat"  verbose="true">
     <arg value="sonar:sonar" />
        </exec>
        <echo message="Build complete" />
    </target>
That is: specify the mvn.bat file location.
But, generally speaking, you solution is better than mine, because it doesn't need to know where is mvn.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the C# plugin uses the Java runner, not Maven, to launch Sonar. Details on setup are here

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C-Sharp+Plugins+Ecosystem

The Java runner is documented here

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+a+simple+Java+Runner

Comment: Sorry, Sonar works well in my environment. I can use cmd, and redirect to the C# project folder, and input 'mvn sonar:sonar' to scan specified code. But did not know how to configure the execution in NAnt.

Comment: So this is really a NANT question? You've tagged your question incorrectly in that case.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe it's my fault not to tag it correctly.
Anyhow, thank you for your sincere help. ^_^